# Sci-fi short story about gamer who defeats his rival by revealing her disfigured face

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short years ago (somewhere between 2007 and 2013). I want to say it was in one of the *Year's Best Science Fiction* anthologies, between 2003 and 2013, but all I can remember is that I found it in a library in either high school or college. I just read Swanwick and Gibson's "Dogfight" and this old memory forced its way to the front of my brain.

A guy, either teenaged or young adult, is trying to beat someone in this popular game. It's either a VR fight or they're remotely piloting special robots. The guy gets more and more consumed with trying to beat his rival, who maybe has a nickname like Medusa or Gorgon and makes a big deal out of never showing their face.

He keeps getting better at the game as he keeps trying to beat the rival, who clearly enjoys the challenge. It's a full obsession to win at any cost and it eventually leads him to discover his opponent is a woman with scars or burns on her face that she's very self-conscious of.

He finally tries to beat her by hacking her webcam and broadcasting her real face to the audience. She had pretty much fallen in love with him by that point and felt a little betrayed.

I remember really liking how the gambits and tactics are described as the two gamers try to trick and outmaneuver each other. I think the nature of the final fight was something like two robot bodies on search-and-destroy, trying to find and then get a good firing angle on each other.

I also liked how the woman is shown falling for the guy, because she thinks he appreciates her as a worthy opponent and wouldn't care if he knew she was scarred. But then he goes ahead and cheats by trying to distract or humiliate her, because his whole identity is wrapped up in this game and he needs to win.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details you can remember, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: That was a useful guide, thank you.

Comment: I recall reading this, but I'm pretty sure it was a book, not a short story. I am checking my reading history and will get back to you as soon as I find it!

Comment: Does your story involve the Pentagon becoming a taller tower with the pentagon twisting as it goes up to make the structure?

Comment: Reminiscent of "[The Girl Who Was Plugged In](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_Who_Was_Plugged_In)" by James Tiptree, Jr.

Comment: @Spencer I don’t see the connection...

Answer (score 10):

## *Insignia* by S.J. Kincaid

### Helpful Links

This is not, in fact, a short story, but a book which I read several months previously. It matches your description *perfectly!* This is most certainly what you were looking for. Here is the link to it on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11115434-insignia), on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insignia_trilogy), and [Common Sense Media](https://www.commonsensemedia.org/book-reviews/insignia).The name of the other fighter is Medusa and the protagonist is Tom Raines.

### Summary

Tom is a virtual-reality gamer who is recruited by the Pentagonal Spire (an innovation of today's Pentagon) to fight in World War Three. This is where he "meets" his rival, Medusa. This is a series, by the way, and *Insignia* is its first book.

### Parts that clearly match from [this summary](http://recaptains.co.uk/2013/11/insignia-by-s-j-kincaid/):

**...rival has a nickname like Medusa or Gorgon**
"[Tom, the main character] has a showdown with Medusa."

**...[discovers] his opponent is a woman with scars or burns on her face that she's very self-conscious of.**
"Tom figures out Medusa’s a girl, and is utterly impressed by her."

Happy reading!